# Linking Intel MKL to R-3.3.2 on MacOS Sierra

Tags: r, lapack, blas, intel-mkl

First of all, I have no idea what I chose when I installed R, but I don't want to reinstall it, and its packages. So, I tried to link Intel MKL to my existing R.

I was following the tutorials here:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/quick-linking-intel-mkl-blas-lapack-to-r

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Shared-BLAS

The problem is there is no `libRblas.so` in my `R_HOME/lib`. Here what `ls` give me in `R_HOME\lib`:

`libR.dylib     libRlapack.dylib    libquadmath.0.dylib libR.dylib.dSYM     libRlapack.dylib.dSYM   libreadline.5.2.dylib libRblas.0.dylib  libgcc_s.1.dylib    libreadline.dylib libRblas.dylib        libgcc_s_x86_64.1.dylib libRblas.dylib.dSYM libgfortran.3.dylib`